# Dynamic SQL with string including variables declaration in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to run dynamic SQL scripts that include declaration of variables?

Example:

**Important note**: this example is only to demonstrate the mechanism I need to implement. The shown calculation is trivial for the sake of simplicity.

I need to return the minimal value between 4 passed values so, programmatically, I create a string that contains the following code:

```
DECLARE @_1 INT = 12 ;
DECLARE @_2 INT = 22 ;
DECLARE @_3 INT = 32 ;
DECLARE @_4 INT = 42 ;
DECLARE @_Min   = NULL ;

SET @_Min = @_1 ;
IF (@_2 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_2 ;
IF (@_3 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_3 ;
IF (@_4 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_4 ;

SELECT @_Min ;
```

Again, all this is contained in a string variable (say `@_Command`).

To execute this and get the result of the calculation, I would be running the following command:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @_l_Command                     , 
                      N'@_l_Result FLOAT OUTPUT'      , 
                      @_l_Result = @_l_Result OUTPUT    ;
```

When running it, I get an error message stating:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.

Obviously I'm doing something syntactically wrong but cannot figure out what it could be.

Comment: Missing Datatype in DECLARE @_Min   = NULL ;

Comment: Your best friend: `PRINT @DynamicSQLVariable;`. If you can't run the the SQL printed out from the `PRINT` statement, then neither can `sp_executesql`. if you're getting a Syntax error, then the reason isn't because you "can't do something" in Dynamic SQL; it's that the syntax of the Dynamic SQL is wrong.

Comment: @Larnu, I was quite sure that it should be possible to declare variables (I've done this type of things using other DBMSs like MySQL and Oracle), so my first guess was that the issue is in somewhere in the syntax.

Comment: @FDavidov I didn't say it wasn't possible? Try this, for example: `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = 'DECLARE @i int = 1; SELECT @i AS i;'; EXEC (@SQL);` works fine. I was introducing you `PRINT`, and that you should be debugging the SQL that it outputs.

Comment: @Larnu that's OK. The test using the PRINT output I did before posting my question of course. See Naeemaei's answer below.

Comment: I don't mean to insinuate that you didn't try debugging with `PRINT`, however, if you had, one would have expected you would have noticed that you missed the declaration of your data type for the variable `@_Min`. As @Faraz has pointed out. :)

Comment: @Larnu that's OK. I didn't take it the way you meant. We all do mistakes regardless of how much we know. Sometimes, our errors are waving their arms in front of our eyes and, for some reason, we don't see them. It happens to me, to everyone. Thanks for the time you spent working on this case. Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can declare variables in dynamic query. 
please set @_Min variale type in query 
I run you query without error

```
DECLARE @_l_Result NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @_l_Command NVARCHAR(MAX)='
DECLARE @_1 INT = 12 ;
DECLARE @_2 INT = 22 ;
DECLARE @_3 INT = 32 ;
DECLARE @_4 INT = 42 ;
DECLARE @_Min int  = NULL ;

SET @_Min = @_1 ;
IF (@_2 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_2 ;
IF (@_3 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_3 ;
IF (@_4 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_4 ;

SELECT @_Min as res ;'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @_l_Command                     , 
                      N'@_l_Result FLOAT OUTPUT'      , 
                      @_l_Result = @_l_Result OUTPUT    ;
```

or

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @_l_Command
```

[image: Your Query]

Comment: Nice!!! I'll check where my error was using your example as a basis and let you know (next week though). Thanks for now.

Comment: Well Naeemaei, not only it works but I'm returning now more than on value (outputs). Great assistance indeed!! (and, of course, you got my vote).

Comment: You Can Use From This Command For Show Created Query In Messages Tab: --->   PRINT @_l_Command

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting the variable type for @_Min,If you need to pass values then you should also pass the inputs as separate inputs while executing *sp_executesql*, like below

```
DECLARE @_l_Command nVarchar(max),@Params nVarchar(max)
SET @_l_Command='SET @_Min = @_1 ;
IF (@_2 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_2 ;
IF (@_3 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_3 ;
IF (@_4 < @_Min) SET @_Min = @_4 ;

SELECT @_Min ;'


SET @Params='@_1 INT,@_2 INT,@_3 INT,@_4 INT,@_Min INT'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @_l_Command,@Params,12,22,32,42,NULL
```

Comment: Since I have the actual values of the calculation inputs, it makes no sense to add them to the parameters list of `sp_executesql` while they could be set as assigned while building the command. This way the `EXECUTE sp_executesql` statement can be generalize for any type of calculations regardless of the number of inputs (which could be 1 to 100).